# Building Github npm package

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I am totally new to npm packages. I have a Github npm package. I have installed all the dependencies and packages which were described in the instruction. Can anyone please suggest me the list of steps to execute in order to install/build/run that package.

The folder abc in c:/ contains the package.json and other package related files and folders.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to that folder and open up terminal command and type in :

```
npm init
```

to setup your node package.json

If you already have that and just want to install the packages in your dependency then do

```
npm install.
```